# Most Efficient Way to Check if Records Exist Prior to Insert in .NET

Tags: c#, sql

I am parsing through JSON data and inserting records to a table in SQL. The problem is the amount of data and having to check each record while in the loop prior to insert which slows down the program.

I am using AddRange() to insert a chunk of data at a time but checking each and every value is causing efficiency issues.

Here is a snippet of code where I perform the loop over the JSON data and check if the value exists:

```
foreach (JObject item in content2)
{
    try
    {
        Assignment assignment = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Assignment>(item.ToString());
        //Begin Assignments
        var assignment_id = (int) item["id"];
        var course_id = (int) item["course_id"];

        if (!CheckIfAssignmentRecordExists(assignment_id))
        {
            newAssignment.Add(assignment);
            log.Info("Inserted Assignment ID: " + assignment_id + " for course id: " + course_id);
            writeCountA = writeCountA + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            log.Info("Skipping Assignment ID: " + assignment_id);              
            skipCountA = skipCountA + 1;
        }
        //End Assignments
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        log.Info("Error Processing: " + (int) item["id"]);
        return;
    }
}
```

Here is the Assignment Check Function:

```
private static bool CheckIfAssignmentRecordExists(int id)
{
    var retVal = false;
    using (var db = new DataContext())
    {
        retVal = db.Assignments.Any(record => record.id == id);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

I've seen other recommendations such as saving to a temporary table and performing a merge but not sure how to accomplish that.

What would be the most efficient way of going about checking for delta data prior to the insert?

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with MVC 5 in .NET. Thanks.

Comment: What problem do you have with your current approach? to me it looks good though

Answer (score 0):

When you say "SQL" do you mean MS SQL Server.  If so, then take a look at the MERGE statement.  You can provide the MERGE statement a recordset to process and it will decide whether or not it exists (MATCH in sql-speak) or not and you can decide whether to INSERT/UPDATE/ignore accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Without you database design and code to insert it is hard to answer this. Though there are a couple of things that you could try with your current code to try to improve efficiency.

1) Change your for each to a Parallel.ForEach so you can check multiple records simultaneously

2) I also believe in a db query FirstOrDefault is more efficient than Any

=====

If this still isn't efficient enough I would look at writing my own stored proc, and calling that and inserting the data with SQLBulkCopy.